# How to configure Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu in a such way that one user will have access to one site only

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost

Thanks for looking into this. I'd like to configure my VPS server in such a way that it can host multiple sites and each site will be accessible by a unique user account. At the same time I'd like to have one master account that will have access to all of the sites.

So for example if I have site1, site2, site3, it would be ideal to have structure like:

```
/home/site1/
/home/site2/
/home/site3/
```

where `/home/siteX/` is a webroot for site X and at the same time home directory for "userX". UserX won't have access to any other directory outside of his home directory.

Ideally (but not mandatory) it would be great if virtual host configuration is autocreated every time I add a new user. This will be pure dev server and I don't plan to add users there other than for accessing the sites.

Thanks again!

Comment: How do you want to authenticate your users? Is http basic authentication ok?

Comment: Since that will be their home directories I imagine they will have ssh/sftp access to the server, but again limited to their directory only. As for the http access, it may or may not be limited by basic auth.

Comment: As far as I understand you don't want to limit access to a site (via http) but to a user's home directory which is not obviously 1:1 to their vhost.

Comment: Yes, apologies that I didn't make it clear. By accessing the folder I meant ssh\sftp access, not http access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to set their homes as chroot.

**SOLUTION 1 - PLESK**

You get this functionality out of the box when using **Plesk***. Many of the VPS providers have Plesk on their offer, usually free up to 10 domains, and paid for 30, 100, etc domains.
It works pretty well on the top of Ubuntu.

With plesk however, your users home isn't in `/home/XX` but in `/var/www/vhosts/site.com`

**SOLUTION 2 - CHROOT/JAILKIT**

On the other hand you may want to configure **chrooted shells** manually, which isn't hard either, but setting it up will eat up a quite few days of your time, especially if you're not in the business of daily server administration. [Jailkit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users) might be an easy solution, however.

**SOLUTION 3 - RBASH**

You can also use **rbash** which is a restricted shell, this is a simple solution, but may or may not suite your needs: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/restrict-linux-users-to-their-home-directories-only/

---

***:** Probably **CPanel** does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and multiple solutions. I couldn't find a free version of Plesk and honestly don't really want to use such a sophisticated service as it might be an overkill for my needs. I checked out Jailkit though and it seems like a perfect solution for me. Will play with it for a while today and see if it works well. Thanks again.